# Specify embeded flash object directory?

Tags: html, flash, object, embedding

How should I change the following code if I want to put my flash object into a directory named "flash/", I tried changing the value to "flash/photo.swf" but it didn't work.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="480" height="400" id="tech" align="middle">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
  <param name="movie" value="photos.swf?xml_path=slides.xml" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="photos.swf?xml_path=slides.xml" quality="high" width="480" height="400" name="tech" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. Have to change the directory in both src and xml_path,

```
src="flash/photos.swf?xml_path=flash/slides.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suppose you change the value to "flash/photo.swf", not "flas/photo.swf"
2. You should modify movie_value and embed_src.
3. why you use "?xml_path=slides.xml", is that a parameter? for Flash or Http?

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. I changed both movie and embeded
3. It is automatically generated by the software.